# Changing location after getting response in colorbox

Tags: jquery, jsp, colorbox

I am working on one module in which I select a company name and it popup a form for password using `colorbox iframe`. when I enter password and submit form I get `json` as response. Now I want to close popup window and redirect page to another page. My code is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var validator = $("#passwordverify").validate({ 
            rules: {  
                password: { 
                    required: true, 
                    minlength: 5 
                } 
            }, 
            messages: {  
                password: { 
                    required: "Provide a password", 
                    rangelength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters") 
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function() { 
                $.ajax({
                    url:"varifypassword.action",
                    type:"post",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{partyid:$("#partyid").val(), password:$("#password").val()},
                    success:function(response){
                        if(response.response == true)
                            {
                                  parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
                                  window.location.replace("main.jsp");
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $("#error").html("Incorrect Password");
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
            }
        });
```

It is working fine but `window.location.replace` is working for same iframe. It opens `main.jsp` in same popup. How can I load it at the place of parent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use one of these approaches already?

```
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
window.opener.location.href = mySite;
```

or

```
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
window.parent.location.href = mySite;
```

Comment: Thank you Christopher Will `window.parent.location.href = mySite;` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a javascript method to the parent window

add following methode outside the iFrame

```
    function ChangeUrlFromParent(url)
    {
    document.location=url;
    }
```

and call the method from the iFrame

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var validator = $("#passwordverify").validate({ 
        rules: {  
            password: { 
                required: true, 
                minlength: 5 
            } 
        }, 
        messages: {  
            password: { 
                required: "Provide a password", 
                rangelength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters") 
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function() { 
            $.ajax({
                url:"varifypassword.action",
                type:"post",
                dataType:"json",
                data:{partyid:$("#partyid").val(), password:$("#password").val()},
                success:function(response){
                    if(response.response == true)
                        {
                              parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
                              ChangeUrlFromParent("main.jsp");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            $("#error").html("Incorrect Password");
                        }
                    }
                }); 
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello iBoonZ, beside the unattractive fact that in this case the logic get moved to the parent window, the function will not be in the scope of the popup. To get this work you need to refer parent as well.